# TypeScript - building .d.ts definition files - Nested functions.

Tags: typescript

I am in the process of creating TypeScript definitions for RiotJS. This lib uses nested functions like so:

```
riot.route( args ); // function
riot.route.parser( args ); // function in function
```

Here is an extract of what I have so far:

```
declare module riot
{
    export function route( callback : Function ) : void
    export function route( to : string ) : void
}
```

I am not sure how to structure the definition for the "riot.route.parser()" nested function and wondering if anyone has any insight to share on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an implementation that uses inline typing :

```
declare var riot: {
    route: {
        (callback: Function): void
        parser: {
            (args): any;
        }
    };

}

riot.route(() => null); // function
riot.route.parser(1); // function in function
```

I recommend you break it up into interfaces, naming them according to a.) either purpose or b.) how actual documentation calls them.

An example to get you started:

```
interface Riot {
    route: {
        (callback: Function): void
        parser: {
            (args): any;
        }
    };

}
declare var riot:Riot;

riot.route(() => null); // function
riot.route.parser(1); // function in function
```

## Update

for function overloads where the return type / number of arguments do not change I recommend Union Types:

```
interface Riot {
    route: {
        (toOrCallback: string|Function): void
        (callback: Function): void
        parser: {
            (args): any;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest how would you overload the 'route' function with definition. i.e. :

 'export function route( callback : Function ) : void
 export function route( to : string ) : void'

Or would you just just any for the callback ?

Comment: Clever - I would give you another thumbs up for that if I could. Thank you again .